# Client asking for AES Channels 1 & 2 render

Tags: mixing, mastering, pro-tools

Hello,

I've rendered audio content for radio and TV/commercials before, but rendering out a simple wav or mp3 has always been sufficient; as long as the ceiling was set to the appropriate level.  However, today a client asked for the audio to be mixed down to "AES Channels 1 & 2."  Is this a simple default AES spec or a certain codec?  I've looked online but can't seem to find anything.  Does the AES have a default setting for TV somewhere that I just can't seem to find?

Any info would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/guidelines/dq/pdf/tv/tv_delivery_of_programmes_to_worldwide_v1.0-2011.pdf page 12

Comment: maybe i'm missing something but in my experience if a spec or client is asking for a "mix down to AES Channels 1 & 2"  they are asking that the stereo mix be layed back to tape (HD, digibeta) digitally (AES) on channels 1 & 2. Not a rendered and delivered BWAV but a tape layback to picture.